# How to get Key Events to work

Tags: java, input, keylistener

I have been messing around with some java code, trying to get a better feel for how the language works, and I came up with this. I have been able to get the ball and frame to work, but I can't get it to move, or even run anymore. It says the last brace needs a semicolon after it, but when I add it, a lot of things become errors. The problem with running first arose when I tried to had the Key Listener, if that helps.

```
package com.edu4java.samplegame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Main extends JPanel {

private static final int ScreenW = 1000;
private static final int ScreenH = 800;
private static final int S_Radius = 25;
private static final int S_X = 100;
private static final int S_Y = 100;
private static final int Step = 100;

private static int x = S_X;             // x at center of the ball
private static int y = S_Y;             // y at center of the ball
private static int radius = S_Radius;   // radius of the ball

private void moveBall() {
   /* x = x + 1;
    y = y + 1;*/
}

KeyListener keyListener = new KeyListener() {
    int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();{
    switch( keyCode ) { 
        case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
            x = x - Step;
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
             x = x + Step;
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
            y = y - Step;
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT :
            y = y + Step;
            break;
     }
  };

@Override 
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
        RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g2d.fillOval(x, y, 30, 30);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Forgotten");
    Main game = new Main();
    frame.add(game);
    frame.setSize(ScreenW, ScreenH);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    while (true) {
        game.moveBall();
        game.repaint();
        Thread.sleep(10);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to register the KeyListener
In your Main class, add a method to create and return a KeyListener (wrap what you have for the KeyListener). Then in main, register the listener, something like this:

```
frame.addKeyListener(main.getKeyListener());
```

Alternatively, you can make Main itself a KeyListener (Main implements KeyListener), implement the methods, then you just just use main:

```
frame.addKeyListener(main);
```

Answer (score 0):

The JPanel is unable to use the 'KeyListener', id suggest you make a new class for the listener like this

```
public class keyListen implements KeyListener {

private Main g;

public keyListen(Main g) {
    this.g = g;
}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    //code

}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    // code

}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    // code
}
```

}

once you have done that you need to register it in your main method as this

```
frame.addKeyListener(new keyListen(g));
```

I'm still confused myself as to why JPanel won't allow the KeyListener, but also a thing to notice is that using a Key event listener might not be the best idea!